# Clojure java.jdbc delete-rows

Tags: jdbc, clojure

When using java.jdbc in clojure is it possible to use delete-rows with a complex WHERE statement. The example is

```
(delete-rows :blogs ["id=?" id])
```

and I want something like this:

```
(delete-rows :blogs ["id=?" id "user_id=?" user_id])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(delete-rows :blogs ["id=? and user_id=?" id user_id])
```